# Xamarin - Swipe to refresh the refresh icon still there after execute command

Tags: android, ios, xamarin

I am using xamarin forms to develop my project, and now I am using the Jason Smith Components to refresh my view.

[Xamarin.Forms-PullToRefreshLayout](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Xamarin.Forms-PullToRefreshLayout)

I am using the following code:

```
        scrollControl.RefreshCommand = RefreshCommand;
        public ICommand RefreshCommand
        {
            get {return new Command(async () => await ContentScrollView_Scrolled()); }
        }
        async Task ContentScrollView_Scrolled()
        {
......
        }
```

After I execute the code, the refresh icon still keep spinning. I tried to put the `scrollControl.isRefreshing = false` at the end. It does not work.

Comment: Can you add full code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok well, this solution is kinda weird, and i found it, since the isrefreshing property is false, so i set the isrefreshing to true at the beginning of code, i thought it will auto set to true so i have to manual it myself, in the end it is work like charm

```
 scrollControl.RefreshCommand = RefreshCommand;
        public ICommand RefreshCommand
        {
            get {return new Command(async () => await ContentScrollView_Scrolled()); }
        }
        async Task ContentScrollView_Scrolled()
        {
        scrollControl.isRefreshing = true;
......
        scrollControl.isRefreshing = false;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that when your refresh completes that you are not updating the IsRefreshing property on the UI thread.  Try this:

```
// after your refresh command completes
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread (() => {
  scrollControl.IsRefreshing = false;
});
```

Comment: Hi jason, in the end, the source not work, when i am debug it, when debug into the scroll event, the isrefreshing is false by default